# Unwind Segue iOS goes back 1 too many VC's

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, unwind-segue

I have a 3 viewcontroller navigation where A presents modal controller B, which presents modal controller C all via segues. C has an unwind segue back to B. It also has an unwind back to A. When I perform action for C to unwind to B, it unwinds but then pops B and goes back to A. This is not what I want, I want it in this case to stay on B. Below are the segues VC C uses.

[image: unwind segues from VC C]

unwindCancel is for when user clicks on a collectionViewCell and goes back to VC B.
prepareForUnwind is just a standard "cancel" button to VC A.

Below is code for didSelectItem to call the unwind in VC C. Below that is prepareForSegue in VC C.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindCancel" sender:self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"unwindCancel"]) {
        GalleryDetailViewController *detailVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        detailVC.colletionCount = self.indexPathToPass;
    }
}
```

VC B unwind in .m file

```
-(IBAction)unwindCancel:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{

    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:self.colletionCount atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft animated:YES];
}
```

VC A unwind in .m file

```
-(IBAction)prepareForUnwind:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When going from C to B, don't use an unwind segue just have C call dismissViewController. If you're committed to using unwind segues, look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013591-CH1-DETDEST) specifically section entitle How an Unwind Segue Determines its Destination View Controller

Answer (score 2):

I guess you confused an unwind-segue's identifier with  unwind-segue's Action method.

If you build an unwind-segue with "prepareForUnwind" action, and then you change this unwind-segue's identifier to "unwindCancel".The problem would appear.

Just make sure the unwind-segue's identifier matches it's action method.

Comment: There are 2 unwind segues from C - one back to the B and one back to A.

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs I recreated your demo,the problem does not exist.So I guess you give the segue  a wrong name.Put "nslog" in your two unwind methodes, and see which one is called.

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs This Post is similar to your :http://stackoverflow.com/q/33181577/4975761

Comment: The name's not wrong but VC C pops off back to A using `prepareForUnwind` as well. When I dragged the segue from the VC, not the button, to Exit, this doesn't happen. I'll try the solution posted, but on first glance it's not a naming error like the solution.