# unWind segue triggered in UISearchBar goes too far

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uitableview, unwind-segue

[image]

Above is my app diagram. I have a `root View controller` that present a `second view controller` modally. And then the `second view controller` will present a `view controller` with `searchBar` via `show segue`.

If users type something in the `searchBar` a `table view` will show(which has no segue relationship with the view controller in the storyboard) with its `cells` populated with all the possible address results. Here if a user tap any prefered cell I would like to perform an unwind segue to go back to `second view controller`.

So in `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` I do `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) 
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToNewTasks", sender: self)`

But this way the segue will go back one step further to `root View controller` not 
`second view controller`.

I think the problem might be the `view controller` with `searchBar` has no `segue` relationship with the `table view` and the `dismiss` method has some impact on the `views stack`. but if I don't use the `dismiss` method the `segue` won't even happen.

I have done some research and found these

[Programmatically defining a new navigation controller order/stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824524/programmatically-defining-a-new-navigation-controller-order-stack/36824849#36824849)

[Calling function from another ViewController in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135402/calling-function-from-another-viewcontroller-in-swift)

[Why does my unwind segue go back too far?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181577/why-does-my-unwind-segue-go-back-too-far)

But they did not really solve situations like mine.

Below is the link for the sample project:

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5ee60abbb9c245feab19862b0989b1f120170617090404/dd2235

Comment: Do you still need help with this issue?

Comment: @Dido I kind of came up with my own solution.. thanks.